# React TypeError when trying to get state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm a newbie trying to get started with react. I'm currently developing a TODO app but I'm getting a TypeError: Todo is null.

The state in my Redux dev tools is showing correctly but I can't figure out what I'm missing/ doing wrong. This is on my Edit page when I'm trying to fill the input fields with the data.

This is my code in EditTodo:

```
const EditTodo = ({ todo: { todo, loading }, createTodo, getCurrentTodo, match, history }) => {
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    description: '',
    responsible: '',
    priority: '',
    completed: false

});

useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentTodo(match.params.id);
    setFormData({
        description: loading || !todo.description ? '' : todo.description,
        responsible: loading || !todo.responsible ? '' : todo.responsible,
        priority: loading || !todo.priority ? '' : todo.priority
    });
}, [getCurrentTodo]);

const {
    description,
    responsible,
    priority,
    completed
} = formData;

const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createTodo(formData, history, true);
};
return (
    <Fragment>
        /*CODE HERE*/
    </Fragment>
)
}

EditTodo.propTypes = {
    createTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getCurrentTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired

};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todo: state.todo
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createTodo, getCurrentTodo })(withRouter(EditTodo));
```

This is being called from my Todos Page:

```
 <Link to={`/edit/${todo._id}`}><i className="fa fa-edit" id="edit"></i></Link>
...
Todos.propTypes = {
getTodos: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
getCurrentTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todo: state.todo
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTodos, getCurrentTodo   })(Todos);
```

This is my getCurrentTodo action:

```
export const getCurrentTodo = id => async dispatch => {
try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/todo/${id}`);

    dispatch({
        type: GET_TODO,
        payload: res.data
    });
} catch (err) {
    dispatch({
        type: TODO_ERROR,
        payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
}
};
```

But I get this error:

```
The above error occurred in the <EditTodo> component:
in EditTodo (created by Context.Consumer)
in withRouter(EditTodo) (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.js:25)
in div (at App.js:21)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.js:19)
in Provider (at App.js:18)
in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

and

```
TypeError: todo is null
```

If someone could help me out I would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to edit this down to a minimal reproduction case, and include the **text** of error messages rather than a screenshot. That being said, the first line is likely your problem: the object destructuring will throw if todo is null or undefined but since you don't seem to be showing us how you're calling it it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: It seems like an issue with you expecting `getCurrentTodo` to update `todo` before the rest of the `useEffect` executes. Most likely, your call to `setFormData` should be done in another `useEffect` that checks for changes to `todo`.

Comment: @JaredSmith I edited the question and tried to make it clearer. If you need more details please ask. How can I destructure the object? It is in the state correctly as I can see it in Redux dev tools

Comment: @lula the error tells you that your problem is in your `EditTodo` component, but *you haven't shown us where you use that component in your code*. As I said before, if `todo` is null or undefined when you pass props in, you'll get that error every time.

Comment: ...as an aside, you say you are a newbie. I don't know if you mean with React, or front-end in general, or coding period. But if it's one of the last two, this is **way** to much to tackle all at once. You've got bleeding edge Javascript, React, hooks, axios, modules, etc. Even if you manage to get it kinda sorta working you won't have any understanding of how or why or more crucially be able to understand what goes wrong when it breaks. If you're just new to React and/or current JS, you can probably make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The error from your screenshot in your original question pointed to your `useEffect` hook assigning `description`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhUAF.png

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentTodo(match.params.id);
    setFormData({
        description: loading || !todo.description ? '' : todo.description,
        responsible: loading || !todo.responsible ? '' : todo.responsible,
        priority: loading || !todo.priority ? '' : todo.priority
    });
}, [getCurrentTodo]);
```

The quick fix would be to do a null check on `todo` before checking `todo.description` and similarly for the others to avoid a `TypeError`:

```
loading || todo === null || !todo.description ? '' : todo.description,
```

The above should be good enough to get past the `TypeError`.

---

Anyway, apart from just fixing the null, I would personally split up `EditTodo` component into 2 components: a container component where `todo` may be `null` and a form component where `todo` will never be `null`. Basically, the container does the null checks before passing `todo` to its form component. I think it will be cleaner and safer handling nulls.